# How to: Single Selection with Multiple DataGridViews

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am pulling records from a SQL database via LINQ and displaying the entries in two separate DataGridViews. I'm wondering what is the best way to allow only one row to be selected between the two components?

For example: If A, B, and C are stored in DGV1. And D, E, and F are stored in DGV2. Only A, B, C, D, E, or F can be selected at a time.

What I've tried so far: Using the SelectionChanged event for each DGV to call ClearSelection() in the other DGV. Obviously this was a horrible idea since it is essentially an infinite loop. I also tried playing around with the CellClick event but it would not account for users changing selection via up/down keys.

Any help is greatly appreciated and please let me know if any extra info is needed.

Comment: Just don't call `ClearSelection()` for the other grid in the `SelectionChanged` event if nothing is selected? i.e. `If (changedGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {OtherGrid.ClearSelection();}`

Comment: That works, thanks. I guess I was just overcomplicating it. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `ClearSelection()` for the other grid in the `SelectionChanged` event if nothing is selected. i.e. `If (changedGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {OtherGrid.ClearSelection();}`